# How to save a product with its custom option information to an another table programmatically in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I create a table in database and save a product by simple product id. Now I want to save custom option information of this product. When show this product on front-end I will be show its selected custom option. Actually I want to save a product as an wishlist item in custom  table.

Anybody can help me??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this :
http://snipplr.com/view/56959/
You are interested in catalog_product_save_after event. Get the product from the event, extract the options that you need and than save them in your custom table.